# Windows 7 tray app to easily switch between audio sources?

Tags: windows-7, audio

I'm looking for a Windows 7 tray app to easily switch between audio sources, i.e. speakers, HDMI, USB headset etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of audio sources? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Isn't it a default feature?

Comment: This one works for me.  One click to change it.  It uses a bat file! so actually you can do ANYTHING in one click.  https://sourceforge.net/projects/soundgadget/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you want to switch sources our outputs?

For switching outputs, try this:

- Right click on the speaker icon in the tray.
- Choose "playback devices".
- Select from the list of playback devices (speakers, hdmi, usb headset,) (the device you want)
- Choose "Set Default"
- Your audio output will instantly switch.

If you need to switch inputs:

- Open volume mixer
- Mute or lower the level on the sources you don't want.

If you do this a lot, and are looking for an app to save you those two extra clicks, this blog post shows three products that [quickly switch audio outputs for Vista and XP](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2008/08/26/easily-change-or-switch-the-default-audio-sound-output-in-windows-vista-and-xp/).

If you find that one of those three apps works well on Windows 7 please let us know.

Comment: Too slow, but thanks I wrote my own program that can do it in less clicks...

Comment: What API did you use?  AutoHotKey or something?  I'm also now looking for a way to do it faster, but the IMMDeviceEnumerator::GetDefaultAudioEndpoint doesn't have a corresponding SetDefaultAudioEnpoint, and the documentation explicitly says that the user can only set the default through the OS, implying that a shortcut app wouldn't be able to do this at all.  (unless you automate OS keys and clicks like AutoHotkey or something.)

Comment: @JL, Care to share the code ?

Answer (score 7):

Here's a freeware app that will do it: [Vista Audio Changer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vachanger/)

> Vista Audio Changer is a system tray application that can change the default sound output device in Windows Vista at the click of a mouse.

[image]

Comment: The `System.Byte[]` stuff doesn't add any credibility; however, hopefuly they've fixed this since 2011 :-)

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for Coastal Audio Changer.

http://coastalaudiochanger.wordpress.com

Answer (score 2):

http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/65079-anyway-use-hotkeys-switch-sound-output.html#post581797

is another option where ALT + 1 (or whatever position the output is on the control panel dialog list is) will switch audio outputs. Just place in the windows startup folder...

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 7, **AudioSwitch** provides an elegant simple solution.  The interface is similar to the improved audio switching capability introduced in Windows 10.

[image]

https://github.com/sirWest/AudioSwitch

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself in need of doing this on a **Mac**, just press `ALT` and then click the volume control at the top of the screen.  A menu with different I/O options will appear. You never know...

Answer (score 0):

For those who already have [**NirCmd**](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) *free swiss army knife* installed, there’s an easy way to do an audio switcher. Just create a shortcut to NirCmd.exe and then edit Target (command line) to this:

```
"C:\Program Files\NirCmd\nircmd.exe" setdefaultsounddevice "playback device name"
```

Create other shortcuts for other sound devices you want to switch to, and add them to Start Menu. Clicking on these shortcuts will switch to corresponding sound device.

This is what [**Sound Gadget**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/soundgadget/) uses internally to do actual switching.