# Windows 8.1 tray app to easily switch between audio sources while calls?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, audio, hdmi, skype

I'm looking for a Windows 8.1 tray app to easily switch between audio sources, i.e. HDMI, audio jack headset 3.0
I'm getting audio out in LED through HDMI, I like to switch headset while getting or making calls[Skype] after finishing calls come back to Defalut audio deveice[HDMI]

If there is no such application, then how could I make that...?
Any suggestions?

NOTE: [Not Duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/106669/windows-7-tray-app-to-easily-switch-between-audio-sources) There answers only for win 7 not worked for win 8.1 or 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://audioswit.ch/er works on anything from win 7 to win 10