# windows 7 audio and HDMI

Tags: windows-7, windows, hdmi, amd-radeon

I am running windows 7 home and running a radeon hd5700 series garaphics card with HDMI out. I have always been able to change audio to "out" and watch vids/films etc on the  tv with sound.

I recently decided to do a format and fresh install due to 4 years of clutter on the pc.

Now the problem i have is after i had loaded everything it worked fine until i installed the drivers for the graphics card. I rebooted and was confronted with a wallpaper screen but could not access the start menu etc. After scouring my defunct memory ( now 48 years old ) i wondered if the display was on the tv as it is linked via a HDMI cable from the graphics card. Sure enough it was and i had to then duplicate screen to put the desktop pc screen as normal.

Later that day i decided to watch a film. It came on the pc screen and the tv (not to worried about that) but no sound. When i chose the "HDMI" sound nothing happened. I went in to properties and disabled the exclusive use but still get the error on test " this programme is being used". Also the TV is showing as monitor 1 and the desktop as monitor 2.

I unistalled and reinstalled the graphics driver and tried again without the HDMI lead plugged in. PC monitor came up as number 1 but as soon as i plugged in the hdmi lead, my desktop went blank and the tv became number 1 again. Please any help ?

Comment: Press Win+P and select screen what you need. Type Win+R write mmsys.cpl and set default audio device.

Comment: Hi,Your time much appreciated but all you have done is offer alternative shortcuts to the problem i have plus its quicker to right click desktop to get access to display properties and also the same with the sound.

Comment: you can use additional app to switch audio for example: [Win7AudioSwitcher](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/auto-switch-speakers-audio-devices-based-on-primary-monitor/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 7 tray app to easily switch between audio sources?](http://superuser.com/questions/106669/windows-7-tray-app-to-easily-switch-between-audio-sources)